# Analyzing derivative of function.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods

I have some function $g: [a,b] \to [a,b]$. I know that $g \in C^1[a,b]$, so $g'(x)$ exists. I want to know, if $\forall x \in [a,b]: |g'(x)| \lt 1$. How can I find out if this is true or not?

P.S. I am not saying all $g$ have the said property, I want to have some kind of test to distinguish fuctions with this property from fuctions without it.

Comment: Short of some description of or constraints on $g$, it isn't possible to say one way or another.

Comment: Explicitly calculating $g'(x)$ and then checking that $|g'(x)| < 1$ is most likely the simplest way to find out if this is true in practice. Any other condition (like checking if $g$ is Lipschitz with constant $1$) I think will be harder or just as hard to check.

Comment: I need exactly to find out if $g$ is Lipschitz, for application on Banach's theorem about fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no restrictions on $g$  apart from those mentioned by you, then clearly your claim is false as you can see by considering the function $g: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ defined by $g(x) = x^2$. In this case $g'(1) = 2$.

After your edit: This the most I can say

If $g$ is a function satisfying the mentioned property then for all $x,y \in [a,b]$
\begin{equation}
|g(y) - g(x)| = \biggl{|}\int_\limits{x}^{y}g'(t)dt\biggr{|} \leq \int_\limits{x}^{y}|g'(t)|dt \leq |y-x|, 
\end{equation}
i.e, the function $g$ is a Lipschitz function with Lipschitz constant $1$. This can also be obtained by applying the Mean Value Theorem.

Conversely, if you have a function $g: [a,b]\to [a,b]$ which is differentiable and satisfies $|g(y) - g(x)|\leq |x-y|$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$, then by the definition of derivative you can see that $|g'(t)| \leq 1$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.

Comment: I am not saying all $g$ have the said property, I want to able to distinguish  fuctions with this property from fuctions without it.

Answer (score 1):

If $0< g'(x) < 1$ everywhere on $[a,b]$, then the following property must hold:

$$b-a > g(b)-g(a).$$

And a suitably similar condition for when $-1 < g'(x) < 0.$

In other words, the function must grow more slowly than $x$ over the interval.

Comment: oh, you are back.

Comment: Could you expand on second part?

Comment: @abel Hmm? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DarkArchon Sure. If $|g'| < 1$, then over an interval the function grows more slowly than either $x$ or $-x$. So if $0 < g' < 1$, we have $b-a > g(b)-g(a)$, and if $-1 < g' < 0$, then we have $a-b > g(a)-g(b)$. Equivalently, this is saying $|b-a| > |g(b)-g(a)|$, which is precisely the result given in the other answer.